# Change project name from default "Application1" name

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, project

I have a WPF project written with C# with project name of "Application1". I want to change this name which is also the namespace of my project class.

Can i do it from project properties? I want to change it to resonable name.
I tried to do it from code behind with no success.

Is the namespace is taken automatically from project name?

```
namespace Application1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying `i tried to do it from code behind`? You can't change namespace during runtime, only before the compilation

Comment: I was going to write the same thing @VMAtm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) To rename a solution

In Solution Explorer, right-click the solution node and then select Rename from the context menu.

Type the new name for your solution.

2.) To rename a project

In Solution Explorer, right-click the project node and then select Rename from the context menu.

Type the new name for your solution.

3.) And last but not least for the Namespace:

-> Project -> Properties -> Default Namespace

Other than that,

Ctrl-H - Find: Application1 Replace: MyName

Source: [How to: Rename Solutions, Projects, and Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e92t91t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old. But recently I also wanted to do the same and change application name in the toast notification. My scenario is bit different but hope this will help.

This is what I got in the beginning:

[image]

But I wanted to change it to this:

[image]

So I achieved desired result by changing **AssemblyInfo.cs** under properties of my wpf application.

In there I changed **AssemblyTitle** & **AssemblyProduct**
Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the project name like right click on the project in Solution Explorer -> rename. And You can change namespace like ctrl + h then in top TextBox write

namespace Application1,

in second

TextBox write namespace YourNewname

From the listbox choose "replace in whole solution"(something liek that) and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

*Rename the project:*

right-click the project and rename

*Rename the default namespace of the project:*

double-click project's properties, choose the **Application** tab, then change what you need:

- **Assembly name**
- **Default namespace**
- click **Assembly information** and change **Title** and **Product**

*Rename the namespace in code-behind (you need to make sure you do it **everywhere**):*

- rename the namespace in all `.cs` and `.xaml.cs` files (for example when you click `App.xaml` node in your project, there will be `App.xaml.cs` class)
- rename the namespace in all `.xaml` files, for example in your `MainWindow.xaml` and `App.xaml` (you need to change x:Class="**MyNewNamespaceName**.App" or x:Class="**MyNewNamespaceName**.MainWindow"):